# Using Lua as script on Windows Embedded Compact 2013

Tags: lua, visual-studio-2013, windows-embedded-compact

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and I have a Virtual Computer with Windows Embedded Compact 2013.
I already have tested some simple C++ applications, just to see if they work on WEC2013 - they do.
Now I am looking for a way to use Lua as a scripting language.

I guess it would work if I embed the right libraries to my project, unfortunately I could not find any libraries that work with the WEC2013-platform.
I have already embeded Lua into a C++ application on win32-platform succesfully.

Now my question is:

Are there some Lua-libraries for WEC2013 or is there any software I could use to reach my aim?

I hope you understand what I'm trying to say, thanks.

Comment: have You tried googling for "Lua Windows CE"? Because there are plenty  of libraries already available, not sure if those are going to fit You needs, but still... [LuaCE](http://luace.codeplex.com/), [LuaWINCE](http://code.google.com/p/lua-wince/), [Lua4WINCE](https://github.com/luaforge/lua4wince). In fact, changes to be done to standard [luaconf.h](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/luaconf.h.html) should be minor to be able to compile it for WEC2013....

Comment: yes I tried googling and the only thing I found was "LUA 5.2.3 for Windows CE 5.0 (ARMV4I)"  I included the library, but it doesn't work.  Well I haven't tried to do some changes to luaconf.h and to be honest I don't even know what to change there :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generated my own Lua-library with Visual Studio, by using the latest sources of Lua, which I have downloaded.
Then I just had to add the library-path and the include directory to my project to make it work.

Comment: I'm getting unresolved external symbols on functions getenv, system, tmpfile and tmpnam when compiling for CE